Missing syntax highlighting in VS Code for 'clicked' method of QPushButton
I am designing a program in Python 3.7.9 based on the PySide6 6.3.2 library in VS Code.
This program contains several buttons as QPushButton, which are connected to functions as such:
prev_button.clicked.connect(go_to_prev)
next_button.clicked.connect(go_to_next)

My problem is that the clicked method, while fully functional and working, isn't being properly highlighted.
I have installed the Python and Qt for Python extensions in VS Code. All other methods of QPushButton are being colored properly, it's only the clicked function that fails to highlight (that I'm aware of). When I type e.g. next_button. and view the suggestions that pop-up, click is among them which I presume simulates a button click, but not clicked.
Here's an example function:
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

def button_clicked():
    print("Button clicked!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Simple GUI Example")

    button = QPushButton("Click me!", window)
    button.clicked.connect(button_clicked)
    button.setGeometry(50, 50, 100, 30)

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

and what I see on my screen using the default VS Code dark theme:

Note that the setGeometry method is being highlighted, but not clicked.connect.

I was able to resolve this by installing the PySide6-stubs library from pip:
pip install PySide6-stubs

The highlighting now appears correctly:


Hi ohshitgorillas, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
